# Prevent user from calling clearInterval manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a javascript interval (`setInterval`) running for a countdown. To stop this interval at a certain time, I use `clearInterval`.
Of course, everyone can easily clear this interval themselves by calling the `clearInterval` function.

So I'm wondering, how can I prevent users from manually stopping the timer, but still be able to stop the timer myself?

Comment: In a browser you can't stop a user doing anything. You can try to hide things but that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could trap the variable you store `setInterval`'s return value in a closure to make it harder to inspect a user could still:

- Access it via a debugger
- Guess the value (it is just an integer)

So, the short answer is that **you can't**. What happens in the user's browser is, ultimately, under the user's control.

If time matters that much, then involve the server in it somehow. (e.g. by requiring data that the server will only release after a certain amount of time).

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
(function() {
  var _clearInterval = window.clearInterval;
    window.clearInterval = function(interval) {
      // _clearInterval(interval);  // Uncomment to enable default behaviour.
  };
})();
```

While this is no foolproof prevention of calling `clearInterval` it significantly implements obstacles for the users to manually call `clearInterval`.

Since the user is in full control of the browser there is no foolproof way to do this other than rewrite the browsers javascript engine, which of course is not very probable you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could at best try and obfuscate the setInterval by adding some scoping to it.

For example you could create an object in JS and assign a method to that object that starts the interval. People could still clearInterval in the console but not without knowing the scope of the interval.

E.g

```
myGlobalObject.intervalMethod.clearInterval(myInt);
```

This isn't bullet proof - it just makes it a little harder to clear the int since writing clearInterval is not enough - you need to know the scope. But anyone who takes the time to read your JS in dev tools will be able to find this code.